# Android Action Bar Up Navigation How to SetParentActivity? Its not working for me

Tags: android, android-actionbar, up-navigation

I have total 9 activity and I want to use Up Navigation Button.I have used 2 parent activity i.e One for Login activity and another for Option activity. Please see the code.

Its working for:
ResetActivity -> Loginactivity; 
ForgotPasswordActivity -> Loginactivity

Rest of them is not working Pl help me to solve the issue.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".LoginActivity"
        android:label=" Login"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".RegisterActivity"
        android:label="Register"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="Forgot password"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LoginActivity" />
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ResetActivity"
        android:label="Reseting password"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".OptionActivity"
        android:label="Option details"
        android:launchMode="singleTop" >
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ProductActivity"
        android:label="Add Product"
        android:parentActivityName=".OptionActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label=":location"
        android:parentActivityName=".OptionActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".HelpActivity"
        android:label="How to use App"
        android:parentActivityName=".OptionActivity" >

    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".ViewActivity"
        android:label="View"
        android:parentActivityName=".OptionActivity" >

    </activity>
```

My LOGIN ACTIVITY CODE:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    Button btnLinkToRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnlinkregister);
    Button btnToForgot = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnforgot);
    Button signIn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signin);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);


    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);


    // SqLite database handler
    db = new UserData(getApplicationContext());


    btnLinkToRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });


    btnToForgot.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent forgot = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                    ForgotPasswordActivity.class);
            startActivity(forgot);

        }
    });


    // Login button Click Event
    signIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            if(name.equals("")&&password.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Username or Password is empty",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            try {


                if (name.length() > 0 && password.length() > 0) {
                    db = new UserData(LoginActivity.this); //create again database to retrive
                    if( db.Login(name, password)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Login is Successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Intent work = new Intent(LoginActivity.this,
                                OptionActivity.class);
                      // work.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                       //work.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(work);
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Username/Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Problem occurred",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });}



private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

}

My REGISTER ACTIVITY CODE:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
    inputUsername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    inputPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
    btnLinkToLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLinkToLoginScreen);
    ActionBar ab = getActionBar();
    ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);



    // Progress dialog
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);

    // SQLite database handler
    db = new UserData(getApplicationContext());


    //When register button is click the database updated
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String name = inputUsername.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

            if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                //inputUsername.setText("");
                //inputPassword.setText("");
                //inputEmail.setText("");
                //registerUser(name, email, password);
                db.addUser(name, email, password);
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Registration is successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent i1 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        LoginActivity.class);
                startActivity(i1);


            }else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please enter your details!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        }
    });

    // Link to Login Screen
    btnLinkToLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

        }
    });

}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch(item.getItemId()){
        case android.R.id.home:
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private void showDialog() {
    if (!pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.show();
}

private void hideDialog() {
    if (pDialog.isShowing())
        pDialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent reg = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this,
            LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(reg);
    finish();
}
```

}

Comment: It worked with two activity bcoz you have used meta-data tags

Comment: I have also used meta-data tags for rest of my activity. It's not working!

Comment: @Bharat I don't see any issues in your Manifest file. Can you share the screenshots of your **LoginActivity**, **OptionActivity** & also can you mention more details about "not working"?
[I hope you've added **setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled()** & **navigateUpFromSameTask** in every non-parent activity].

Comment: @Srikar . I have added login & register code above. I want to use Up Navigation from register to Login. "not working" :When I press Up navigation it coming out of my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you click the Register button from the LoginActivity right? In the *btnLinkToRegister* of LoginActivity, you are calling *finish();* after starting the RegisterActivity. The *finish()* method closes the activity, thus, when you are press the up button (or press the back button), the LoginActivity cannot be opened anymore, so it will go to the homescreen.

Comment: Can you look at this problem and Help me..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32569184/android-select-specific-column-value-in-autocompletetextview-and-display-locatio?noredirect=1#comment52994289_32569184