# Android select specific column value in AutocompleteTextview and display location by use of sqlite db?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-sqlite, autocompletetextview

How to get specific values form columns "Condition" and get the latitude & Longitude.

My SQLITE database columns are:

```
    //Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_TID = "id";
public static final String KEY_TreeID = "treeid";
public static final String KEY_TCONDITION = "condition";
public static final String KEY_TLATITUDE = "latitude";
public static final String KEY_TLONGITUDE = "longitude";


 private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE if not exists " + TABLE_TREE + "("
        + KEY_TID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + KEY_TreeID + " , "
        + KEY_TCONDITION + " , "
        + KEY_TLATITUDE + " double, "
        + KEY_TLONGITUDE + " double "
        +");";


ID  Condition   Latitude    Longitude
1   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
2   Good        12.897485   15.425974
3   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
4   Poor        12.897485   15.425974
5   Poor        12.897485   15.425974
6   Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
7   Fair        12.897485   15.425974
8   Good        12.897485   15.425974
9   Good        12.897485   15.425974
10  Excellent   12.897485   15.425974
```

My MapActivity:
I have used One AutoCompleteTextView for my "Condition" = 'Excellent', 'Good','Poor' & 'Fair'. And One Button to click to show Google Map with Markers.

```
 inputSearch = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.et_search);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, conditions);
    inputSearch.setThreshold(1);
    inputSearch.setAdapter(adapter1);
    btMap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MapButton);
```

If My AutoCompleteTextView is Empty and Click Button, It Should show all my 10 location, as shown in sqlite db table.

"This is working correctly"

```
  btMap.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            String search = inputSearch.getText().toString();

            if(search.equals("")) {
                double latitude = 0;
                double longitude = 0;
                String mark;

                // SQLite database handler
                db = new TreeData(getApplicationContext());



                Cursor locationCursor = db.getLocations();

                locationCursor.moveToFirst();

                do {
                    latitude = locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE));
                    longitude = locationCursor.getDouble(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE));

                    mark = locationCursor.getString(locationCursor
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID));

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(mark));


                } while (locationCursor.moveToNext());

            }
```

ELSE If I select 'Excellent'  from my AutoCompleteTextview and Click Button, It should shown only 'Excellent' Row Latitude and Longitude i.e ID 1,3,6 & 10

"This is not working"

```
if(search.length() > 0){


                Cursor c = db.getSelectedLocations(search);

                c.moveToFirst();

                do {
                   double latitude1 = c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE));
                    double longitude1 = c.getDouble(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE));

                    String marker = c.getString(c
                            .getColumnIndex(SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID));

                    LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude1, longitude1);

                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(location).title(marker));


                } while (c.moveToNext());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "All is Well", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
});}
```

To read my database I have used following code:

```
  //Getting all the 10 Location information in MapsActivity
public Cursor getLocations(){
    db = SQLiteHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] selecteditems = {SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE,SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE, SQLiteHandler.KEY_TCONDITION,SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_TREE,selecteditems,null,null,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}

    //Get only selected row in AutoCompleteTextView information in MapsActivity
public Cursor getSelectedLocations(String search){
    db = SQLiteHandler.getWritableDatabase();
    String[] selecteditems = {SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLATITUDE,SQLiteHandler.KEY_TLONGITUDE, SQLiteHandler.KEY_TCONDITION,SQLiteHandler.KEY_TreeID};
    String where = SQLiteHandler.KEY_TCONDITION + "=?";
    String[] whereArgs = new String[]{search+""};
    Cursor cursor = db.query(SQLiteHandler.TABLE_TREE,selecteditems,where,whereArgs,null,null,null,null);
    return cursor;
}
```

ERROR

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.bharat.plantnow, PID: 2124
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.bharat.plantnow.MapsActivity$1.onClick(MapsActivity.java:132)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Getting `All is Well` in Toast?

Comment: Yes.After If Statement. But it show error When Else statement execute first.